# Mass invarint of bbbar pair by Pythia

Tags: c++

I'm not so expert in C++, but I try to make  a simple program to calculate
and plot the bbbar pair mass invariant distribution by pythia in pp collision
(pp -> bbbar), taking the events from .lhe file.

Now about the program attached here , i made the steps as following but
nothing shown in the Histogram .. may be there is some thing wrong in the loop ..
the steps :

- booked the Histogram
- start the event loop
- defined iBottom to account for b decay
  -start the particle loop
- defined b , bbar
  -start the particle loop
- make a contour to find the pairs
- calculate the invM.

So any help about that ? to know how to make such program
if any one knows about pythia ..

```
// The program

#include <iostream>
// Header file to access Pythia 8 program elements.
#include "Pythia.h"
// ROOT, for histogramming.
#include "TH1.h"
// ROOT, for interactive graphics.
#include "TVirtualPad.h"

{#include "TApplication.h"
// ROOT, for saving file.
#include "TFile.h"
using namespace Pythia8;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

// Create the ROOT application environment.
TApplication theApp("hist", &argc, argv);

// create Pythia object and set up generation
Pythia pythia;
pythia.readString("PartonLevel:MI = off");
pythia.init("events.lhe"); 
pythia.readString("Beams:eCM = 14000.");
pythia.readString("PhaseSpace:pTHatMin = 20.");
pythia.init();

// Create file on which histograms can be saved.
TFile* outFile = new TFile("hist.root", "RECREATE");

TH1F *Mbbbar = new TH1F("MbB","MbB invariant mass", 0,0.,2000.);


// Begin event loop. Genera1te event; skip if generation aborted.
for (int iEvent = 0; iEvent<100; ++iEvent)
{
int iBottom = 0;

if(!pythia.next()) continue;
for (int i = 0; i< pythia.event.size(); ++i)
{
if (pythia.event[i].id() == 5) iBottom = i;

// Look for BQuarks among decay products.
      vector<int> b, bbar;
      for (int i = 0; i< pythia.event.size(); ++i) {
        int id = pythia.event[i].id();  
        if (id ==  5) b.push_back(i);
        if (id == -5) bbar.push_back(i);



// Check whether pair(s) present.
      int N = bbar.size();
      int n = b.size();
      if (N + n > 1) {

// Fill masses of BQuarks pair.
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < n - 1; ++i1)
       for (int i2 = 0; i2 < N - 1; ++i2)
          Mbbbar->Fill(
            (pythia.event[b[i1]].p() +pythia.event[bbar[i2]].p()).mCalc() );

}
}
}
}

pythia.stat();
Mbbbar->Draw();
std::cout << "\nDouble click on the histogram window to quit.\n";
gPad->WaitPrimitive();
// Save histogram on file and close file.
Mbbbar->Write();
delete outFile;

// Done
return 0;
}
```

Thank you,
Safinaz

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be both about the domain specific knowledge and about the programming knowledge which you will have trouble finding here. It would be best if you tried to explain your intention in basic terms and only ask how to implement those semantics in C++.

For starters it looks like you have waaay to many loop unnecessarily nested which leads to weird semantics (you should be careful with declaring multiple `int i` with the same name too). I tried to guess what it is that you want to do and explain it a little with comments

```
// Begin event loop. Genera1te event; skip if generation aborted.
int numEvent = 0;
int maxEvents = 100;
//as long as pytha.next() generates something and we have processed less than 100 events
while(pythia.next() && numEvent++ < maxEvents){
    vector<int> b, bbar;

    //for each particle in the event
    for (int i = 0; i < pythia.event.size(); ++i){
        //add the particle index to b if the id() is 5
        //otherwise add it to bbar
        switch(pythia.event[i].id()){
            case 5: 
                b.push_back(i);
                break;
            case -5: 
                bbar.push_back(i);
                break;
        }
    }

    int bSize  = b.size();
    int bbSize = bbar.size();
    //for every possible pair of id()=5 and id()=-5 particles found during this event
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < bSize; ++i1)
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < bbSize; ++i2)
            Mbbbar->Fill(
            (pythia.event[b[i1]].p() + pythia.event[bbar[i2]].p()).mCalc());
}
```

Additionally you should step through and check if the code that you think is executed is even executed. If doing this in debug mode is not possible for some reason you can also print debug messages for example:

```
std::cout << "starting event loop" << std::endl;
while(pythia.next() && numEvent++ < maxEvents){
    std::cout << "starting event cycle number " << numEvent << " with " << pythia.event.size() << " particles" << std::endl;
    //...

    std::cout << "found " << b.size() << " particles with id()=5" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "found " << bbar.size() << " particles with id()=-5" << std::endl; 
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < bSize; ++i1)
    //...
```